# How to make an if statement to disable select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three select menus where the user selects a subject, year and season. However, I want it so that if the user selects the year '2019', the 'Fall' option will get disabled.

```html
<select name="Subject">                  
    <option value="Math">Math</option>
    <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
    <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
    <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
</select>

<select name="Year">                  
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>

<select name="Season">                  
    <option value="Spring">Spring</option>
    <option value="Fall">Fall</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Add event on change. When selected value is 2019 simply disable select of season with Spring as option selected. Because there is no use of select if there is only one option to choose

Comment: Please provide what have you done so far apart from only html. Apart from that I can help only by saying you need to find the select by name and then track the change and when any change is made try to find the current value and compare with 2019 and update disabled attribute in the other case remove the disable attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create and event handler for the Year's change event and disable the season based on what Year's new value is.

https://jsfiddle.net/075fnm4a/

HTML

```
<select name="Subject">                  
    <option value="Math">Math</option>
    <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
    <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
    <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
</select>

<select name="Year">                  
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>

<select name="Season">                  
    <option value="Spring">Spring</option>
    <option value="Fall">Fall</option>
</select>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('select[name="Year"]').on('change',function(){
    var $this = $(this);  
    $('select[name="Season"]').find('option[value="Fall"]').prop('disabled', ($this.val() == '2019') ); // disabled or enabled 
  });

  $('select[name="Year"]').trigger('change');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this.

```js
document.querySelector('#year').onchange = ev => {
  const value = ev.target.value;
  if (value === '2019') {
    document.querySelector('#fall').disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#fall').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="Subject">                  
    <option value="Math">Math</option>
    <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
    <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
    <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
</select>

<select name="Year" id="year">                  
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>

<select name="Season">                  
    <option value="Spring">Spring</option>
    <option value="Fall" id="fall" disabled>Fall</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="Subject">                  
    <option value="Math">Math</option>
    <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
    <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
    <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
</select>

<select name="Year" id="years">                  
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>

<select name="Season" id="seasons">                  
    <option value="Spring">Spring</option>
    <option value="Fall">Fall</option>
</select>

$('#years').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val()==='2019'){
        $("#seasons option").each(function()
        {
            if($(this).val() === 'Fall'){
                $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `onchange` event and bind `callback` to it that get `season select` element and enable and disable `Fall` season according to selection value

```
  <select name="Subject">                  
    <option value="Math">Math</option>
    <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
    <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
    <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
</select>

<select name="Year" onchange="changeYear(this.value)">                  
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>

<select name="Season">                  
    <option value="Spring" >Spring</option>
    <option value="Fall" disabled>Fall</option>
</select>

<script>
function changeYear(value)
{
    var seasons = document.getElementsByName("Season")[0].options;
    var fallSeason = Array.apply(null, seasons).find(season => season.value === 'Fall');
    fallSeason.disabled = (value==='2019')
}
</script>
```